# How to make a filter look for info in only one column with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I am using the following code to filter data in my table:

```
function searchFilter(ftr,table){
    ftr = '#'+ftr;
    table = '#'+table;
    var $rows = $(table+' tbody tr');
    $(ftr).change(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });

}
```

But if there is information repeated in other columns it will show them too.
How can I be specific on what column I want the filter to work? Let's say the id of this column is `betaDate`.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you would get the index of the column

```
var searchIndex = $("#betaDate").index();
```

and in the filter row you can use the index

```
$(this).find("td").eq(searchIndex).text()...
```

---

And another way of doing it [logic might be off, but basic idea]

```
var index = 1; //starts at one not zero!
var text = "1";
$("table tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")")
    .filter( function() {
        return $(this).text()!==text; 
     })
     .parent()
         .addClass("hide");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKfew/)

Comment: the first solution worked perfectly, now what if I want it to look in two different columns? `betaDate` and `originalDate` ?

Comment: `var tds = $(this).find("td"); var txt1 = tds.eq(searchIndex).text(); var txt2 = tds.eq(searchIndex2).text();`

Comment: duh! got it... modified `var text` and added the extra check

Comment: I did it different... `var text = $(this).find("td").eq(betaIndex).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();` and then `text = text + $(this).find("td").eq(oriIndex).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();`

Comment: Do not do the td look up multiple times. It will make the code slower. Look it up one time.

Comment: But then what do I return? `!~tds.indexOf(val);`??

Comment: You are overthinking it. It is the same exact thing, just store the tds like I did and use it instead of looking it up twice. `tds.eq(betaIndex).text().replace...`

Comment: Yea, I get that, but doing it the way you are saying (to avoid `find("td")` happening twice and making the code faster) it gives me an error `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Post the code to a jsfiddle or pastebin, you have another issue.

Comment: You should not be using tds with indexOf...That is the problem. tds has nothing to do with the text of the cell. Look at my comment 4 up..